# when slide fragment with gridview, it happens java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a avtivity that use viewpager fragment with gridview in android. Every gridview contains eight apps icon of system and the number of fragment is dynamic. It works well but slide to the third fragment. sorry for my english.

In this current state of the app, I get the following Exception:

```
   V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 0, com.android.providers.downloads.ui getView
V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 0, com.android.providers.downloads.ui getView
V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 0, com.android.providers.downloads.ui getView
V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 0, com.android.providers.downloads.ui getView
V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 0, com.android.providers.downloads.ui getView
V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 1, com.android.quicksearchbox getView
V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 2, com.rockchip.gamecontrolsetting getView
V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 3, com.android.apkinstaller getView
V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 4, com.android.rockchip getView
V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 5, com.android.speechrecorder getView
V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 6, com.android.videoeditor getView
V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 7, com.rockchip.wfd getView
V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 0, com.rockchip.mediacenter getView
V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 0, com.rockchip.mediacenter getView
V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 0, com.rockchip.mediacenter getView
V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 0, com.rockchip.mediacenter getView
V/test_GridAdapter( 1418): The position is 0, com.rockchip.mediacenter getView
D/AndroidRuntime( 1418): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 1418): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c79300)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418): Process: com.example.zhengjy.ljlauncher, PID: 1418
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at com.example.zhengjy.ljlauncher.GridAdapter.getView(GridAdapter.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1345)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:345)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:287)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:421)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1233)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1626)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1996)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1753)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1005)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5750)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The activiy xml is :

```
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/pagerIndicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="5" />
```

The grid.xml is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="100dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp" />
```

The grid_item xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/app_grid_item"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/app_margin">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/app_icon"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_icon_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_icon_height"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/label_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_icon"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minWidth="20dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The GridAdapter is:

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;

private GridItems[] items;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textTitle;
}

public GridAdapter(Context context, GridItems[] items) {

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;

}

...

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (items != null && position >= 0 && position < getCount()) {
        return items[position];
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if (items != null && position >= 0 && position < getCount()) {
        return items[position].id;
    }
    return 0;
}

public void setItemsList(GridItems[] locations) {
    this.items = locations;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.app_grid_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.imageView = ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon));
        viewHolder.textTitle =  ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_name));
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    GridItems gridItems = items[position];
    viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(gridItems.appInfo.icon);
    viewHolder.textTitle.setText(gridItems.appInfo.name);
    Log.v(TAG, "The position is " + position + ", " + gridItems.appInfo.packageName + " getView");

    return convertView;
}
```

}

The FragmentStatePagerAdapter is :

```
   private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<GridFragment> fragments;
    FragmentManager fm;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<GridFragment> gridFragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm = fm;
        this.fragments = gridFragments;
    }

    @Override
    public GridFragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Which line in `GridAdapter.java` is line #95 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null pointer seems to be in your `getView()` method. Determine which item is null with the following:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.app_grid_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.imageView = ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon));
        viewHolder.textTitle =  ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_name));
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    if (viewHolder == null) {
        Log.e("GridAdapter", "viewHolder was null")
        return convertView;
    }
    GridItems gridItems = items[position];
    if (gridItems == null || gridItems.appInfo == null) {
        Log.e("GridAdapter", "gridItems or appInfo was null")
        return convertView;
    }
    viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(gridItems.appInfo.icon);
    viewHolder.textTitle.setText(gridItems.appInfo.name);
    Log.v(TAG, "The position is " + position + ", " + gridItems.appInfo.packageName + " getView");

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Oh my God! I forget check the gridItems, it really has null items. thanks you very much!!!